# How can I animate an element changing its opacity at the same time?

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation

I would like that an element makes an animation from left to right changing its opacity from 0 to 1.

I have animated the element but I cannot change its opacity at the same time.

This is the code that I have by the moment:

```js
$("#moveIt").animate({left:0, opacity:"show"}, 1500);
```

```css
#moveIt{
  position: relative;
  left: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="moveIt">
  <span>This is the div that I want to move</span>
</div>
```

I know that there is a function on `JQuery` called **[`fadeTo`](https://api.jquery.com/fadeTo/)** but I do not know how to combine it with **[`animate`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)** function to change the opacity of the element at the same time I animate the element.

I can wrap the `animate` function with `fadeTo` function but it changes the opacity of the element **before** the animate function fires, not **at the same time**, as I need.

How can I change the `opacity` of the element at the same time I animate it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The opacity property can take a value from 0.0 - 1.0.

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_transparency.asp

Change

```
$("#moveIt").animate({left:0, opacity:"show"}, 1500);
```

To

```
$("#moveIt").animate({left:0, opacity:1}, 1500);
```

if you want to fade in then set opacity 0 on page load using css and change it to 1 using .animate()

```js
$("#moveIt").animate({left:0, opacity: 1}, 1500);
```

```css
#moveIt{
  position: relative;
  left: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: red;
  opacity : 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="moveIt">
  <span>This is the div that I want to move</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! I did not notice that I could change the `opacity` value on `animate` function. I feel so dumb now...

Comment: NP :) Glad to help :)

Answer (score 1):

Initialize the opacity.

```js
$("#moveIt").animate({left:0, opacity: 1}, 1500); // set opacity to 1
```

```css
#moveIt{
  position: relative;
  left: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: red;
  opacity : 0; /* opacity to zero */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="moveIt">
  <span>This is the div that I want to move</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It was exactly was I was looking for but I finally thought that @Deep answer was a bit more complete. +1 btw

Answer (score 0):

You can replace .animate() with a more CSS solution.

Example:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#moveIt").addClass('animate');
});
```

```css
.element {
  position: relative;
  left: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: red;
  transition: all 1.5s; /* change speed here (1.5s)*/
  opacity: 0;
}

 /* Values to animate to */
.animate {
  opacity: 1;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="moveIt" class='element'>
  <span>This is the div that I want to move</span>
</div>
```